# how to find table head of a td after selecting with jquery

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-selectors

[image]

hi
as you can see in above image,i'm creating a simple calendar to use in my project.

Html for table:

```
<table>
<tr><th>time</th><th>2012-12-23</th>etc..</tr>
<tr><th>09:00AM</th><td></td><td></td>etc...</tr>
```

and i i use jquery(selectable) to let those td's selectable.

**My Question:** When user click save it post the form data to php file, how can i also include the date and time of selected td?

For example: I want when user click save now (above img) it send along **"2012-12-24 12:00 PM"**

---

problem solved "raina77ow" answer.

but from the comments and my -ve votes i think that my question was short in details so i added my code to make things clear:0

HTML

```
  <FORM id='booking_form'>
A form that u see above in img</form><a id='save'>save</a>
        <h1>Week Calendar</h1>
        <div class="body">
            <table id='schedule'>
                <thead>
                <tr><th>Time</th><?foreach($cal[0] as $d)echo "<th>$d</th>";//$cal[0]contain week days starting from today?></tr>
                </thead>
                <?//create our table by nice clean loop
                $start_time = "09:00:00";
            $end_time = "20:00:00";
            while(strtotime($start_time) <= strtotime($end_time)){?>
            <tr>
                <th><?=date("h:i A", strtotime($start_time));?></th>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <?
            $start_time = date("H:i:s", strtotime("$start_time +60 minutes"));
            }//end while
            ?>

            <tr></tr>
    </table>
```

**JS when click save button**

```
var datas=$('#booking_form').serialize();
        var request = $.ajax({
                        url: "./booking/add",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: datas,
                        dataType: "html"
                        });

        request.done(function(msg) {$info.html( msg );});
        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {$info.html( "<div id='error'>" + textStatus +"</div>");});
        request.success(function(data){$info.html(data);});
        return false;
```

And here was my question, how to add the time and date of selected field to that ajax post.
thanks for your answers, i came up with adding 2 hidden input in #booking_form name=date and name=time and added selected option to add values to them.

```
    $schedule.selectable({
    filter: 'td',
    selected: function( event, ui ) {
        var time = $(ui.selected).parent().children(':first').text();
            date = $(ui.selected).closest('table').children(':first').find('th').eq($(ui.selected).index()).text();
        $('#booking_form').find('[name=date]').val(date);
        $('#booking_form').find('[name=time]').val(time);
    }
    });
```

[I find this as the Best answer](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZJ3C/2/)  thanks alot

Comment: That depends entirely on the existing code which you do not have shared. Also what have you tried so far? Please follow the [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice) you needed to confirm before posting *any* question. Keep in mind that only you want something and you ask yourself how it is programmed does not qualify as a programming question per-se. - as per the tags it looks like you know the answer already: [Jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) - please consult the manual for your support options.

Comment: added more details, i didnt wana make question look big earlier !, and yea i knew its a selector problem but i kept trying and trying couldnt figure out the .closest('table') !!, thanks any way

Comment: This answer has been closed so I'm giving the answer in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZJ3C/2/) because `jQuery.selectable` has it's own method to do this kind of job and this is the proper way, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy to get the time - as it's the first cell of the clicked row. To get the 'date' column, we can use the `index` method.

```
$('td').click(function() {
  var $cell = $(this);
    time = $cell.parent().children(':first').text();
    date = $cell.closest('table').children(':first').find('th').eq($cell.index()).text();
    alert(date + ' ' + time);
});​
```

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/txk7A/).

Comment: `jQuery.selectable` has it's own method to do this kind of job and [this is the proper way](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZJ3C/2/), IMO.

Comment: @raina77ow,you saved my day man.God bless you

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('td').click(function() {
    var $td = $(this);
    var $th = $td.closest('table').find('th').eq($td.index());

    // Get the header text...
    alert($th.text());

    var $firstTD = $td.closest('tr').find('td:first');

    // Get the first td text...
    alert($firstTD.text());
});​
```

Comment: `jQuery.selectable` has it's own method to do this kind of job and [this is the proper way](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZJ3C/2/), IMO.

Answer (score 1):

With just plain JavaScript, once you have the `<td>`, you can get:

```
var time = td.parentNode.cells[0].firstChild.nodeValue,
    date = td.parentNode.parentNode.rows[0].cells[td.cellIndex].firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Comment: i got no clue wt u talking about pal, sorry im not a js guy :(

Comment: `jQuery.selectable` has it's own method to do this kind of job and [this is the proper way](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZJ3C/2/), IMO.